# Oracle: Mixing IN and LIKE, is it possible?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to do someting like this?

Ie.

IN ('%1', '%2')

**The values are not few**

How would you solve this task?

Comment: Where are you getting the values from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only a few, just combine them with `or`:

```
column like '%1' or column like '%2' or...
```

If you have a lot, you can create a table with the patterns and join to it.

```
create table matches (
   match char(10)
);

insert into matches values
    ('%1'),('%2'),...;

select * from table
    inner join matches on table.column like matches.match;
```

That has some issues with duplicate rows if a single row matches more than one pattern, but you can modify it depending on what kind of final output you want.

As a third option, you could use `substr()` rather than `like` if they are all the same length:

```
select * from table where substr(column,-1,1) in ('1','2',...)
```

This checks if the last character is in the set of values.

Comment: Can you make your example with temporary tables?

Comment: @Gik25, sure that is possible.  I'm not an Oracle user, though.  Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: I'm not so good, but I will try. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You could also use REGEXP_LIKE instead of LIKE. It can be more flexible in this type of situation.

To get everything that ends with '1' or '2' just use:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(col_name, '[12]$')
```

The [12] means match 1 or 2. The $ means match the end of the string.

If you need something such as this:

```
LIKE '%1' OR LIKE '%2' or LIKE '%A' or LIKE '%W'
```

... you just have to add the other characters within the square brackets:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(col_name, '[12AW]$')
```

Or, if you wanted *anything* that ends with a digit you could use this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(col_name, '[[:digit:]]$'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using like itself?

```
Column LIKE '%1' OR Column LIKE '%2'
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically same as examples of others but closest to your example:

```
SELECT deptno, empno, ename FROM scott.emp
 WHERE job IN 
   (SELECT job FROM scott.emp WHERE job Like ('SALE%') OR job Like ('MANAG%'))
/
```